# Change background JQuery depending on img src

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

So I am trying to change the background color of a div after the page loads.
The div with the background and the img are inside an li.
When the mouse enters the .dlmain div I check the img src and give the div .darkbg a background depending on the img src

THE ISSUE: It shows me the correct img src the first time and second time but then on the next div I enter it shows the previous divs img src. I have about 100 divs that the mouse enters and background color should be changed

Am I supposed to have a .each function here? I tried this with no luck

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("mouseenter", ".dlmain", function () {
        if ($('.carimg').attr('src') == '/css/1359532013.jpg') {

            $(".darkbg").css({
                "backgroundColor": "#EE1C25"
            });
            alert($('.carimg').attr('src'));

        } else if ($('.carimg').attr('src') == '/css/1359532047.jpg') {
            $(".darkbg").css({
                "backgroundColor": "blue"
            });
            alert($('.carimg').attr('src'));

        } else {
            alert($('.carimg').attr('src'));
        }
    });

});
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<li id="13592635281366253285" class="myli" style="width:170px;height:170px;">
    <div class="favs"></div>
    <div class="mylimg" style="background:url(/images/th135926352813662532851.jpg) 50% 50% no-         repeat;"></div>
    <div class="darkbg" style="background-color: rgb(238, 28, 37); opacity: 0;"></div>
    <div class="dlprice">$69.99</div>
    <div class="dlmain" style="top: 153px;">
    <img class="carimg" src="/css/1359532047.jpg">
</li>
    <li id="13592635281366253092" class="myli" style="width:170px;height:170px;">
    <div class="favs"></div>
    <div class="mylimg" style="background:url(/images/th135926352813662530921.jpg) 50% 50% no-repeat;"></div>
    <div class="darkbg" style="background-color: rgb(238, 28, 37); opacity: 0;"></div>
    <div class="dlprice">$59.99</div>
    <div class="dlmain" style="top: 153px;">
    <img class="carimg" src="/css/1359532013.jpg">
</li>

Thank you in advanced for any help
```

Comment: please share the html also

Comment: I have added the html, the img itself is added to the div in a different function on mouse enter div.dlmain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find the element relative to the current hovered element. you need to target the `carimg` and `darkbg` elements with the same `li` as the entered `dlmain` element. So use [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to find the `li` element and then use [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) in the `li` element to find the other 2 elements

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("mouseenter", ".dlmain", function () {
        var $li = $(this).closest('li'),
            src = $li.find('.carimg').attr('src'),
            $darkbg = $li.find('.darkbg')
            if (src == '/css/1359532013.jpg') {
                $darkbg.css({
                    "backgroundColor": "#EE1C25"
                });
            } else if (src == '/css/1359532047.jpg') {
                $darkbg.css({
                    "backgroundColor": "blue"
                });
            } else {}
        alert(src);
    });
});
```

---

Another tweak that can be applied is

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var backgrounds = {
        '/css/1359532013.jpg': '#EE1C25',
        '/css/1359532047.jpg': 'blue'
    };
    $(document).on("mouseenter", ".dlmain", function () {
        var $li = $(this).closest('li'),
            src = $li.find('.carimg').attr('src'),
            $darkbg = $li.find('.darkbg');

        $darkbg.css({
            "backgroundColor": backgrounds[src]
        });
        alert(src);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Arun. I see so my mistake was that it wasn't grabbing the img src relative to the hovered div element I was currently on. This works perfectly. I still get one issue where when I initially enter the .dlmain element it doesn't grab the img src but I have to enter the div again in order for it to grab it. How can I make sure that the img is there inside the li before this function is executed?

Comment: @AdrianBegi whether the contents of like is loaded dynamically?

Comment: Yes the content is loaded dynamically...I thought I could make sure by using the .on function but I then realized that the img inside the li itself is loaded once I hover over div.dlmain

Answer (score 0):

if you have different '.carimg' for each divs, you should pick the specific one.
$('.carimg').attr('src') is giving you the same value for all the divs.

If the img '.carimg' and div '.darkbg' are in the current div '.dlmain', please try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("mouseenter", ".dlmain", function () {
        var $this=$(this);
        if ($this.find(‘.carimg').attr('src') == '/css/1359532013.jpg') {

            $this.find(“.darkbg").css({
                "backgroundColor": "#EE1C25"
            });
            alert($this.find('.carimg').attr('src'));

        } else if ($this.find('.carimg').attr('src') == '/css/1359532047.jpg') {
            $this.find(".darkbg").css({
                "backgroundColor": "blue"
            });
            alert($this.find('.carimg').attr('src'));

        } else {
            alert($this.find('.carimg').attr('src'));
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: You are right it was giving me the same img src every time. I tried your code but for some reason I can not figure out why it is not working (you have one minor which I fixed ‘ instead of ') But it seems like this should work perfectly, but I get undefined for the img src every time. Thank you for your help non the less